# ¿Cómo hacer que un echo aparezca dentro de una tabla en HTML?

Tags: php, bootstrap

Quisiera saber cómo hacer que los "echo" de este codigo aparezcan dentro de una datatable de bootstrap? Algo así como la imagen de aquí abajo.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

**Imagen:**

[image: Imagen de como quisiera que quedara]

**Código: (PHP)**

```
$menta = xploit("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name&limit=5000&access_token=" . $token);
$jason = json_decode($menta);
foreach ($jason->data as $data) {

    xploit("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?uid=".$data->id."&method=delete&access_token=" . $token);
       echo "Facebook ID " . $data->id . " Person : " . $data->name . " Success <br>";
}
```

Comment: En lo particular para poder mostrar informacion en un dataTable, estoy recurriendo a este código: <td label style="font-size:10px;"><?=$datoFacebookID?></td>, si estas manejando PHP esta es la forma que yo conozco, entre las etiquetas <?= ?>  de esta manera se logra imprimir los valores que se traen desde una consulta a la BD con Mysql.

Comment: "$datoFacebookID"  es solo un ejemplo,  lo utilice como nombre de una variable que podría traer algún tipo de dato o valor.  En tu caso los valores que traes con el xploit asignarlos a alguna variable y luego colocar esta como se indica.  Espero te ayude un poco esta información

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso lo que tienes que hacer es `echo` del código html con las classes. Tu código quedaría así:

```
$menta = xploit("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name&limit=5000&access_token=" . $token);
$jason = json_decode($menta);

echo '<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th scope="col">Facebook ID</th><th scope="col">Person</th><th scope="col">Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

foreach ($jason->data as $data) {
    xploit("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?uid=".$data->id."&method=delete&access_token=" . $token);

    echo '<tr><td>' . $data->id . '</td><td>' . $data->name . '</td><td>Success</td></tr>';
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Otra alternativa sin tantos `echo` sería así:

```
<?php
$menta = xploit("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name&limit=5000&access_token=" . $token);
$jason = json_decode($menta);
?>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Facebook ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Person</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($jason->data as $data) {
            xploit("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?uid=".$data->id."&method=delete&access_token=" . $token); ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $data->id; ?></td>
                <td><?= $data->name; ?></td>
                <td>Success</td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Amigoooo! Muchísimas gracias de verdad, que detalle!